# Odata url conversion of date using between

Tags: c#, java, android, odata, odata4j

I have query like this

```
 select * 
from xxx 
where dates between '2012-10-26' and '2012-10-27'
```

How can i convert this to URL in Odata Services

Comment: I solved this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be queried like this: 
        `http://service/odata/Products?$filter=dates gt datetime'2012-10-26' and dates lt datetime'2012-10-27`'

Comment: With time in URL its not working.how can i writen URL with time

Answer (score 0):

i solved this query converted to URL like this

```
$format=json&$filter=year(LastModifiedDate)+ge+2012+and+month(LastModifiedDate)+ge+09+and+day(LastModifiedDate)+ge+25+and+hour(LastModifiedDate)+ge+00+and+minute(LastModifiedDate)+ge+00+and+second(LastModifiedDate)+ge+00+and+year(LastModifiedDate)+le+2012+and+month(LastModifiedDate)+le+12+and+day(LastModifiedDate)+le+31+and+hour(LastModifiedDate)+le+23+and+minute(LastModifiedDate)+le+59+and+second(LastModifiedDate)+le+59
```